# Why doesn't this markdown directive using Angular (from the blog) work?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I was reading through the [Angular blog](http://blog.angularjs.org/2012/05/custom-components-part-1.html) (way down at the bottom from May 11th, 2012) and I stumbled upon a bit of code that created a `markdown` tag.  However, even in the [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/bradlygreen/8bENp/), this doesn't appear to work.  I've read through the directives developer documentation and don't really understand why this doesn't work.

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <markdown>
# Hello World!
- Zeppelin
- That guy
- Kronos
    </markdown>
</div>
```

What is missing? (Why doesn't this markdown directive using Angular (from the blog) work?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would seem as though the `showdown.js` file being served from github is being read as the MIME type ('text/plain') so jsfiddle is not actually treating it as JavaScript.

If you check out my updated fiddle, in which I have take the showdown.js code and pasted it into jsfiddle, then you will see it working.

[Check out the JSFiddle Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/8bENp/232/)

So the code is actually working, just not within the existing jsfiddle example :)

Comment: From the console: `Refused to execute script from `https://raw.github.com/coreyti/showdown/master/compressed/showdown.js' because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled. `

Comment: You can use the site rawgithub.com to bypass this issue